# php Use 0 key as value in URL to retrieve data

Tags: php, laravel

So recently I was working on fixing an older system which is using keys from an array to retrieve certain data.

This is the array with several brands of cars, the key is used to filter certain things so the URL would look like http://example.com/page?brands=1&foo=bar

```
public static $carBrandGroups = [
    0 => 'Volvo',
    1 => 'BMW',
    2 => 'Renault',
    3 => 'Tesla',
    4 => 'Opel',
    5 => 'Peugeot',
    6 => 'Toyota',
    7 => 'Mercedes',
    8 => 'Honda',
    9 => 'Fiat',
]
```

Now the system works and retrieves everything except when 0 is passed which is logical since 0 is considered empty. I believe there must be a way, is there?

The function which passes additional information is shown below:

```
public static function getCarBrandGroup($modelNumber)
{
    if ($modelNumber == 999) {
        return 'Other';
    }

    if (isset(self::$carBrandGroups[$modelNumber[0]])) {
        return self::$carBrandGroups[$modelNumber[0]];
    }

    return 'Unknown';
}
```

The modelNumber is three digits so everything that starts with 0 is a volvo model, so 001 is Volvo V40, 101 is BMW X6 and so on...

Like I stated above, everything works except for 0, is there a way to make this work and seen as a value?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is `$modelNumber` actually set to string `001`? Or is it just `1`?

Comment: [Works fine for me.](https://3v4l.org/9mC3n)

Comment: @AlexHowansky It is not set to string, so it must be just 1.

Comment: Yeah, it's working for me too... What version of PHP are you on?

Comment: I'm guessing you are casting intentionally or unintentionally the 001 into integer and trying to extract digits individually, so when you have 001 and cast it into integer you lose some of the digits...

Comment: Just echo the modelnumber out and you'll see what is different than expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll asume the `$modelNumber` is a string with 3 characters in it. In your example you're passing `$modelNumber[0]` and it should result in an error.

**Option 1: split your string into an array**

```
public static function getCarBrandGroup($modelNumber)
{
    if ($modelNumber == 999) {
        return 'Other';
    }
    // Split your string into an array
    $modelNumber = str_split($modelNumber);
    if (isset(self::$carBrandGroups[$modelNumber[0]])) {
        return self::$carBrandGroups[$modelNumber[0]];
    }

    return 'Unknown';
}
```

**Option 2: use the first character to get the required model**

```
public static function getCarBrandGroup($modelNumber)
{
    if ($modelNumber == 999) {
        return 'Other';
    }
    // Get the first character using substr
    $modelNumber = substr($modelNumber, 0, 1);
    if (isset(self::$carBrandGroups[$modelNumber])) {
        return self::$carBrandGroups[$modelNumber];
    }

    return 'Unknown';
}
```

**Option 3: Or if you like shorthand & fancy PHP7 operators:**

```
public static function getCarBrandGroup($modelNumber)
{
    if ($modelNumber == 999) {
        return 'Other';
    }

    return self::$carBrandGroups[substr($modelNumber, 0, 1)] ?? 'Unknown';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely getting passed integer `1` instead of string `001`. If you know that each code is supposed to have exactly three digits, then you can force a zero-padded reformat and cast to string at the same time by using `sprintf()`:

```
public static function getCarBrandGroup($modelNumber)
{
    $modelNumber = sprintf('%03d', $modelNumber);
    if ($modelNumber === '999') {
        return 'Other';
    }
    if (isset(self::$carBrandGroups[$modelNumber[0]])) {
        return self::$carBrandGroups[$modelNumber[0]];
    }
    return 'Unknown';
}
```

Now, you can pass either `(string) "001"` or `(int) 1`.